# Callback for kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange not called in one case

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, core-audio

I want to be notified if headphones are plugged in or plugged out. I'm currently doing this using a property listener like this:

AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, myCallback, self);

This works perfectly well in all cases except in one, it goes like this:

1. Launch, iPhone is unmuted, no headphones plugged in
2. Switch the mute button on: The callback is called, good
3. Plug in the headphones now: Callback is not called, not good

Is there another property I should consider? Is there a special case involving the mute button I'm not aware of?

I'm using an iPhone 3GS and iOS 4.1.

Thanks a lot for any help!
Patrick

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue.  The AudioRouteChange callback does not fire sometimes when switching from Silent to Ring.  I can reproduce this issue reliably by muting the device, then unmuting it about 1 second later.  This issue doesn't happen when flipping the switch back and forth quickly or if you wait longer than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug/feature only happens when using an audio session category affected by the silent switch (e.g. kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound). kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback for example works as expected.